# PHP (Linux): list files that have been executed

Tags: php, linux, debugging

I'm debugging fairly complex PHP/AngularJS application written in custom framework. Documentation is almost non-existent and there is are no clear naming and folder conventions.

The biggest challenge for me is finding which files were executed in a particular request. The application has several different ways of autoloading and it has over 4500 PHP files.

Is it possible to find out which files were executed without modifying the code of application? I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.

If no, what would be the next best way to do this? I'm aware of  get_included_files function, but I don't think it would help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dedicated test environment, then make sure the cache is oversized, run your tests and see what got loaded into the opcode cache. For newer PHP installations, use [opcache_get_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-status.php)() for the older, APC cache, use [apc_cache_info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cache-info.php)()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can find out this without modifying your application code.

But I think that for the PHP part [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) could help, if you know where your endpoint is. With this you can reproduce one process, like a exception stacktrace.

Another one: you could use a debugger like [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) and go through the system with some brakepoints, so that you can see how the application flow is.